# Accessing children of a child in react component returning JSX

Tags: reactjs

I have two components

```
function Main(){
  return (
       <Parent>
         <Child/> //returns a paragraph
       </Parent>
    )
}
```

when i try to access the props.children of the `<Child/>` component from the `<Parent/>` like so

```
function Parent({children}){
     console.log(children.props.children)
    return children
}
```

I get an object like this

```
type: Object
key: null
ref: null
props: {}
_owner: FiberNode
_store: Object
```

How can I access a props.children of the `<Child/>` component from the parent component ?

Answer (score 0):

That is an anti-pattern.

If you need to access the children in the parent, you will do something like:

```
function Main(){
  return (
       <Parent>
         <Child>
           <p>Hello Caleb</p>
         </Child>
       </Parent>
    )
```

Or access it directly in `<Child>`:

```
function Child ({children}){
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello Caleb</p>
      {children}
    </div>
}
```

In React, everything flows from top to bottom, creating a tree. Accessing any part of the tree should be done from the same point as a parent. Doing it from a child is inefficient and hard to work with.